# How to minor updates to Drupal-6 with shared hosting

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've got Drupal working on a shared host, and I uploaded some modules from my home system successfully, but I've got the message that there is a security update for my version, and I should update immediately.

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do that.  It seems like the update is an entire new installation.  I originally installed it using the hosting company's installer, Fantastico.  Should I simply over-write the existing installation with the new files?  Or ignore the message?  I realize I shouldn't over-write the sites folder, or anything I've modified.

The instructions that come with the download seem to be for a major version upgrade, and are way too much trouble for frequent security updates.  Searching Drupal's site shows many other methods, but no indication of anything official.  And some were ridiculously error-prone, and not really useful.

I don't have shell access to the hosting site, although I can pay extra to get it if I really need to. Or, maybe I can clone the site on my local Linux system, do the update using a script, then upload the whole thing.

Does anyone have experience with this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With only FTP access you should:

1. Download and extract the new Drupal version.
2. Delete the sites folder (in the downloaded Drupal), this is very important.
3. Put your site in maintainance mode.
4. Upload the content of the new Drupal (not the sites folder). This should give you a new version of all the Drupal core files, but leave the sites folder intact where you have your custom and contrib modules, your settings.php file and your uploaded files.
5. Run update.php as user 1.
6. Lastly put your site in online mode again.

Comment: Thanks, That's pretty much what I thought, although I wanted to make sure I didn't screw it up somehow.  I probably should do it on my local Linux system first - I installed it and got it working, although I haven't done anything with it yet.  If I have the same modules and theme on my home system, would it be a good idea to check the update on it, then upload that installation to the hosted site?

Wordpress sure does make this part easy, but so far, I like everything else about Drupal better than Wordpress.

Comment: Finally got around to testing your solution, and it worked well.  Was nice to have all the steps laid out - Thanks for your help.

Comment: By 'delete the sites folder', he means the one INSIDE the Drupal .tar file, not the one on your live FTP. Hope you see this before you get it mixed up!

Comment: Thanks - I actually knew that, and at first was even going to mention it, but didn't since his point 4 kind of made it clearer. But I'm glad you mentioned it for any others that might read it, since this was a nice, simple, and clear set of instructions.